# eclipse variable highlighting with different colors in one variable

Tags: eclipse, colors, highlighting

i would like to have different colors highliting for one variable if it maches some rules or sth (doesnt need to be too complex)

for example i often see code like:

```
Node switch1 = new Node();
Node switch2 = new Node();
Line line1 = new Line();
Line line2 = new Line();
line1.add(switch1);
line2.add(switch2);
```

if now there would be an error like:

```
line2.add(switch1);
```

it would be really nice if this can be visualized better with colors for example.

any ideas anyone?

additional infos: 
eclipse java ee version indigo on win7 (if matters)